# How do I obtain a background task scheduler identifier Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, background-process, identifier

I am trying to get my app to do some background refreshes in Xcode.  I have set the permissions in entitlements and in my plist I have added "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers and added some strings below for the identifiers BUT I don't know how to create the identifiers.
So my question is as simple as it may seem
How do I create/get my background task scheduler identifiers for my app in Xcode?

Help, give me an example or somewhere where it is explained?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean what strings to use or do you mean how to create background tasks that use those identifiers.  For the former you can use anything you like, but by convention you would use something based on your your domain, but reversed, much like a bundle id.  For example; "com.mydomain.myapp.periodicindex" or "org.myorg.AppName.refresh" or whatever

Comment: Ok Thanks.  I meant the former.  So I used @"com.creatucate.iphoneMQTT.refresh" and it seems to work.  I am working on background task trying to get MQTT to work with it but with very little luck.  I can get it to get called once in a while since Apple in their "wisdom" want to sacrifice app functionality for battery life who knows when it will fire.  But when it does it only looks for updates which I don't know how that might look in background task.  If you want to look at it and give me some pointers just search under my user id.  Thanks

Comment: MQTT probably isn't the right approach for receiving updates in an iOS app that isn't in the foreground.   You should use push notifications

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Could you point me to an example

Comment: I mean that there is no way to reliably schedule background execution for specific intervals on iOS, which is what you seem to want to do.  If you want to deliver data to your app then a much better approach is to use push notifications.  You could have a server task that subscribed to MQTT and send a silent push to your app when there was data.